# Interchanging integrals; example

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to understand how to interchange integrals. I was hoping someone could verify if the following is correct

$\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f(x,y) dy dx$.

I know this doesn't say much of the theory since it's just one example, but it's just for making sure i've understood it correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: your original integral is over $0<y<x<\infty$, so $y$ is between $0$ and $x$. Hence it should be
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy \, dx. $$

Comment: And one should add of course that this is only valid for certain $f$'s, e.g. non-negative ones.

Comment: Oh, sorry. That was actually what I tried to write. Thanks! :D